# knockout virtual elements and using "with" without a container element

Tags: binding, knockout.js

Can someone tell me why this works:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="jqDialog: {title: drugName}">
        //contents of a jquery ui modal
    </div>
</div>
```

But trying to do the same with KO virtual elements does not work:

```
<!-- ko with: selectedItem -->
    <div id="dialog" data-bind="jqDialog: {title: drugName}">
        //contents of a jquery ui modal
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: drugName is not defined;
Bindings value: jqDialog: {title: drugName}
```

I'd like to get rid of that div wrapper which just holds the data-bind attribute.  I figured the virtual elements would make this a breeze.

**Edit**: Here's kind of the core to the page (though it won't run in the fiddle), http://jsfiddle.net/B8g5J/

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can you provide any more detail or an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on all browsers or only some?

Comment: Without being able to see what `selectedItem` actually contains, my best guess is that `drugName` is not a property of `selectedItem`.  It could be that the property name is actually "DrugName" or "Name" or something else.  The error you're seeing is consistent with what I've described, that is, attempting to bind an element to a property name that doesn't exist.

Comment: selectedItem is an individual element of the preferredDrugs array.  You can see what that looks like at http://jsfiddle.net/Gm64C/2/ (it's the data object at the top of the JavaScript pane, ignore everything else).  I can console selectedItem out and it does hold that same structure and does have the drugName prop.  And yeah, I agree with you, it seems to be failing at binding a prop it can't find.  I'm a bit stumped as why, though as it works when not using the KO virtual element.

Comment: Michael, I'm only really testing in Firefox, I'm just playing with KO, trying to learn it by using an existing internal web service I have access to.  We have an outsourced mobile app that uses KO coming internally before the end of year.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle so it actually runs: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/B8g5J/1/  But of course it doesn't load any data. You should be able to update it to load some static data in the correct format so we can test it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have sorted this out, but is it possible that your server is configured to remove comments?

See: [Knockout.js Virtual Elements Work Locally But Not Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474682/knockout-js-virtual-elements-work-locally-but-not-remotely)