# Knockout.js Virtual Elements Work Locally But Not Remotely

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this issue where a virtual knockout template will not bind properly when hosted remotely, but works perfectly fine locally.

This is the page in question: http://www.brandonmartinez.com/presentations/20121109-AdvancedKnockoutJs/index.html#8

Here's my template:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko template: {name: 'product-template', foreach: Computers} --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko template: {name: 'product-template', foreach: Phones} --><!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

And the basis of the javascript:

```
function Slide005And006ViewModel() {
    var vm = this;

    function ProductViewModel(productName, description) {
        var pvm = this;

            pvm.ProductName = ko.observable(productName);
            pvm.Description = ko.observable(description);
    }

    vm.Computers = ko.observableArray([new ProductViewModel('iMac', 'All-in-One Computer'), new ProductViewModel('Latitude', 'Dell Laptop'), new ProductViewModel('Surface', 'Microsoft Tablet')]);
    vm.Phones = ko.observableArray([new ProductViewModel('iPhone', 'Awesome'), new ProductViewModel('Lumia', 'Not Bad'), new ProductViewModel('Anything Android', 'Crap')]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new Slide005And006ViewModel(), document.getElementById('slide006'));
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Full source available here: http://www.brandonmartinez.com/presentations/20121109-AdvancedKnockoutJs/source.zip

Comment: The actual ko template comment `<!-- ko template: {name: 'product-template', foreach: Computers} --><!-- /ko -->` was stripped out from your deployed html, you can check it with view source. I guess your web server or deployment process strips out the comments because also the Google HTML5 slide template part is missing from the top...

Comment: You sir, are correct. My host is stripping stuff. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My host was stripping out comments, which KO uses for the templates. Thanks to @nemesv for catching that!